# FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

When trying to build the APK I am facing this problem

> Note:
> C:\Users\UX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\zego_express_engine-3.7.0\android\src\main\java\im\zego\zego_express_engine\internal\ZegoExpressEngineMethodHandler.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be thrown from the native side of the **zego_express_engine** plugin and not **firebase cloud messaging** plugin.

Often times, they are warnings and wont break the compilation of the APK. You can't fix the issues from your end as they can only be attended to by the plugin authors.

You can ignore them as they are warnings and wont break your APK.